# Does John Fogerty Talk Southern?

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics, southern-white-vernacular-english

What is it that makes people think, erroneously, that Creedence Clearwater Revival are from the South? Is it something in the way the singer John Fogerty pronounces?

In fact he's from California and he doesn't sound Southern to me. I wonder whether his real accent (such as saying "toinin" and "boinin" for "turning" and "burning" in his song Proud Mary) make him sound Southern to the rest of the world, and whether the rest of the world would be right in thinking this.

Here are some of their hits:

- [Bad Moon Rising](https://www.ask.com/youtube?q=creedence%20clearwater%20revival%20lyrics&v=zUQiUFZ5RDw)
- [Have You Ever Seen The Rain](https://www.ask.com/youtube?q=creedence%20clearwater%20revival%20lyrics&v=zUQiUFZ5RDw)
- [Proud Mary](https://www.ask.com/youtube?q=creedence%20clearwater%20revival%20lyrics&v=zUQiUFZ5RDw)

Comment: Fogerty is sounding rustic rather than strictly Southern.

Comment: He does sound southern to me. nothing specific about his pronunciation, rather the musicality of his accent, it's really hard to describe in words, but there's something very "laid back" back in his accent. he stretches some of the words like they do in the south

Comment: For what it's worth, that "boinin'/toinin'" thing isn't Fogerty's "real accent" at all; I've heard him acknowledge, in an interview with Terry Gross on her radio program "Fresh Air," that he adopted that pronunciation (along with his raspy singing tone) in deliberate imitation of African-American blues singers that he admired. Many other white, non-Southern rock singers of his generation, including quite a few non-Americans, use(d) similarly affected accents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a band singing about riverboats and bayous whose lead singer's accent is 1) non-rhotic, even beyond the singing convention of dropping r's, (river, ever, before) 2) monophthongized long i, perhaps the most distinctive feature of Southern American English, and 3) g-dropping (-in' for -ing) though not exclusive to the South, adds to the grits 'n' bacon grease flavor. He doesn't, however, pronounce "can't" as "cain't," but that only gets the accent down from the mountains, but not out of the South.

As for the odd diphthongs in *Proud Mary*, I think they were part of the old New Orleans accent as well as parts of Mississippi and Alabama. There was a woman from MS interviewed in Ken Burns' WWII docu who still spoke that way. I recall certain speakers of AAVE also using those diphthongs, but they were all born around 1900 and are long since gone.

Why shouldn't a singer from California affect a Southern accent when it suits the style and material? After all, Tom Jones is Welsh.

Comment: I thought about this answer for around thirty minutes, reading Wikipedia and Merriam-Websters. I think I get points 1 & 3, but I'm still stumped about 2. What word would we Suthunus pronounce distinctively with the monophthongized long i? Do you mean the way Georgians might "towk lok this" (when they talk like this)?  (BTW, the Mississippi River is from Minnesota, and Mark Twain was from Missouri. And while I think it's pretty hard to sing with an affected regional accent, my point wasn't that nobody could do it; my point was that I don't hear Fogerty's accent as Southern.)

Comment: The long i in General American is a diphthong composed of *ah* gliding quickly to an *ee* sound. Southern American English either drops the glide entirely, though not in all environments for some speakers, or glides slightly to a vowel further back. All accents except New Orleans do this. Your hypothetical Georgian even starts with a back vowel.

Answer (score 0):

His ‘singing accent’ reminds me a bit of Dr. John.  It’s not a typical Southern drawl , more specifically like a New Orleans accent.  Always thought it sounded exactly right actually.