# Which American dialect pronounces "heard" as "hu-yd"?

Tags: dialects, accent

There is an American English dialect/accent that pronounces words like "heard" and "bird" as "hu-yd" and "bu-yd".  One example of this would be CCR's song "I Heard it Through the Grapevine".  Another is LaMonica Garrett's character in the series "1883".  It's fairly subtle, but still distinctive and although I've often heard it, I can't place it geographically.

Can anyone help identify it?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what sound you're trying to represent with "hu-eed".  Can you think of a word that rhymes with "hu-eed"?  When I listen the the Credence version of *I Heard It Through the Grape Vine*, I hear the same "oy" (if you're into IPA: /ɔɪ/) vowel sound you'd expect to hear in "choice" or "coil".  Is that what you're hearing?

Comment: Creedence Clearwater Revival sings in a Southern/New Orleans accent. But they're actually from the SF Bay area, so I don't know how authentic it is.  [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424265/does-john-fogerty-talk-southern). And LaMonica Garrett is also from the SF Bay area, but he also may be speaking with a different accent for the series. People from the San Francisco area generally pronounce *bird* the same way that most Americans do.

Comment: @Juhasz yes, that's what I was going for.  Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: @PeterShor I knew that CCR was from SF, but didn't know that LaMonica Garrett was; that's interesting.  And I agree, I don't think that's the source.  Neither speak like that in interviews.  But I believe it is an authentic accent as I've heard it elsewhere.  I'm just not sure what accent it is or where it is from.

Comment: If a question needs to be updated, please edit the question itself, besides communicating through comments.

Comment: @AndyBonner got it.  Just still wasn't sure how to best represent it, but I tried.

Comment: The sound that you describe in your, now edited post, is still not correct, IMHO. I would read/pronounce "bu-yd" as "boo-id", rather than "boid", or "boyd", which would be better - I only finally understood what sound you meant after reading [Juhasz's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585396/which-american-dialect-pronounces-heard-as-hu-yd#comment1464196_585396). This issue, the sound that you are trying to describe, illustrates the need to use the phonetic alphabet (IPA), in order to be clear as to what you mean.

Comment: [Spaceballs (1987)](https://youtu.be/itTS7CEMd_M?t=90) - *"Yogurt!?!"*

Comment: sounds like heid not hoyd to me

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short answer: Brooklyn English and New Orleans English.

Longer answer: at present, virtually no still-spoken varieties of American English feature this merger, but in the past, it was common in some accents in New York (stereotypically in *Brooklynese*) and in New Orleans English.

What we hear in Creedence Clearwater Revival's version of *I Heard It Through the Grapevine* is called the curl-coil merger.

Here's some of what the Wikipedia article has to say about this merger:

> In some cases, particularly in New York City, the NURSE sound gliding from a schwa upwards even led to a phonemic merger of the vowel classes associated with the General American phonemes /ɔɪ/ as in CHOICE with the /ɜr/ of NURSE; thus, words like *coil* and *curl*, as well as *voice* and *verse*, were homophones...The merger is responsible for the "Brooklynese" stereotypes of *bird* sounding like *boid* and *thirty-third* sounding like *toity-toid*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English#Coil%E2%80%93curl_merger

This feature of the Brooklyn accent is, let's say, old-fashioned.  According to the same article, virtually no native New Yorkers born after 1950 speak this way.  This feature of Brooklynese remains familiar to younger people because of cultural artifacts from the early 20th century, such as *The Three Stooges* or Bugs Bunny.*

But John Fogerty, the lead singer of CCR, is not singing with a Brooklyn accent.  It's more of a New Orleans accent, as would befit the singer of *Born on the Bayou*.

That same Wikipedia article explains that, although most American Southern accents are "non-rhotic" (they don't pronounce /r/ after a vowel, unless there's another vowel sound after it), they do not feature the coil-curl merger.  An exception was the New Orleans accent.

However, as in Brooklyn, this merger is dying out.  Old blues and (Black) rock and roll singers that Fogerty admired may have spoken this way, but very few people in New Orleans (or anywhere) speak like this today.

---

*According to Bugs Bunny's voice actor, Mel Blanc, Bugs actually has a Flatbush accent, which is equal parts Brooklyn and Bronx (https://walkoffame.com/bugs-bunny/).

Comment: The Brooklyn *Hoyd it* equates with *Toydee toyd* street (33rd) and *pretty goyls* (girls). The R drops also when you see the *docta*. Then it adds in when you have to say *mincher* (minchah prayers).

Comment: Thanks @Juhasz. That makes perfect sense and probably explains where I've heard it as I grew up in southern Mississippi.  I was unable to find anything indicating Thomas (LaMonica Garrett's 1883 character) was from New Orleans, but perhaps that's what he was going for.  And you're absolutely right.  I'd forgotten but Bugs did it too, as in "Albuquerque".

Comment: In all cases, the sound belongs to the slangy or not-highly educated.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I can imagine *mincher amidah* (i.e. before the /ɑ/ as an intrusive, linking-r), but do/did you hear people saying *mincher* in isolation, or *mincher prayers*?

Comment: Oh, yes. Gotta go to mincher.

Comment: I would say that non-rhoticity of most Southern accents is dying out as well.

Comment: You hear another example in Gee, Officer Krupke (at least in the original cast recording), in the lines "It's just his neurosis that ought be coybed / He's psychologically destoybed!" I'm sure it appears in other songs too but it's so strong here that as a child I missed the *b* and thought "destoyed" was an actual word until sometime late in high school.

Comment: @MarkFoskey Honestly, I would say that most regional accents in the U.S. are dying out in general. Not dead yet, of course, but dying. As a millennial, most (not all certainly, but most) millennials I know sound about the same whether they're from Florida, rural Alabama, Ohio, San Francisco, or New York City. Regional accents still seem to be more common among boomers (and moreso in the generations before them,) but seem much less common in the younger generations.

Comment: Foggerty was from Southern California.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for the 'geographic region' for the word 'heard' when pronounced to rhyme with void, as in the CCR John Fogerty version of I Heard It Through the Grapevine.  Many answers gave you phonetic explanations.   But for the geography, the 'sound' you are hearing is New Orleans.  Fogerty modeled many of his themes as well as his lyrics, including pronunciation, after the images and street patois of that famous area.  Born on the Bayou, New Orleans, and others. The ties to that city and area are so noticeable that a very frequent question about Fogerty and the boys is, "aren't they from Louisiana?'  Quora has an entire post on that subject! https://www.quora.com/How-come-Creedence-Clearwater-Revival-whose-members-are-all-from-California-spills-its-love-to-Louisiana-in-every-other-song.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, it does help.  Having grown up in the 70s in southern MS, very close to New Orleans, it also explains why the accent was so familiar to me.  I just couldn't quite place it.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Except for those with rhotacism (inability to roll R), pretty much all American accents pronounce the r sound in what linguists call the "NURSE" set of words (heard,worse,perverted,girl,world,etc) even if the accent is otherwise non-rhotic. The dropping of r in the NURSE set in North American English is really limited to those natives of Brooklyn, New Orleans and Charleton SC that are a minimum of 80 years old.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).